# Burning the Tekkit and Tecknic pack tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm asking to remove the [minecraft-tekkit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-tekkit) and [minecraft-technic-pack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-technic-pack) because in all the cases when they're used they were actually referring to a specific mod in that pack (normally [minecraft-buildcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-buildcraft)) rather than the pack/launcher itself.

This makes it difficult to see which mod they're referring to, especially seeing as they tend not to mention the specific mod in the question either.

Comment: More to the point: Why do we have so many damn meta-tags for Minecraft to begin with? What other games get this treatment?

Comment: @Fluttershy The mods do tend to change the game quite significantly, so you do tend to get experts in particular mods.

Comment: Then... Shouldn't every WoW expansion have their own tags? What makes Minecraft so special?

Comment: @Fluttershy Minecraft has 7 subtags and 2 spinoff release tags; Diablo has 6 and 3, respectively. ME3 has 3 and 3, respectively. Skyrim and StarCraft are outliers in that they don't have any, but I suspect SC has non-namespaced subtags

Comment: @Fluttershy [Yes](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5223/remove-the-tag-synonyms-for-world-of-warcraft-on-wow-cataclysm-and-cataclys) it [should](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/introducing-a-new-tag-for-world-of-warcraft-mists-of-pandaria). The way we treat WoW is untenable given how we treat other games.

Comment: @Fluttershy uh... what's so meta about these tags?

Comment: @badp I think he meant to say sub-tags.

Comment: @Fluttershy WoW expansions are very different from Minecraft Mods. The crux of it is that WoW expansions are sequential (you can't have one without the other), whereas Minecraft mods are not.

Comment: @FAE I did indeed. Thanks for not correcting me when I told you about it the first time! =P

Comment: @RavenDreamer I'm not really understanding how that crux plays into this situation. I'm just of the opinion that since these mods wouldn't run without Minecraft in the first place, the Minecraft tag is sufficient. Any additional information can be provided in the question.

Comment: As somebody who doesn't use most of these mods, I actually find it annoying to come across most questions tagged with minecraft as well as minecraft-technic -- most of the time, these questions ask something specifically about content in the technic pack, which doesn't interest me (and I can't contribute to). If anything, I'd keep the tags for minecraft-tekkit and minecraft-technic, but stop also tagging them with minecraft unless the question also applies to the base game.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if it's possible for us to reframe the question to be about a specific mod instead of a mod pack, I agree using a modpack tag is unnecessary. Several of the questions you retagged were of that ilk, and I'm for those.

But looking at the rest of the questions tagged with the ones you want to burninate, it is possible to ask about a modpack in general:

- [How can I use the Zeppelin mod in singleplayer Tekkit?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80430/how-can-i-use-the-zeppelin-mod-in-singleplayer-tekkit)
  Not asking about a specific mod's functions: it's asking if the mod can be used with the pack. Should be tagged Tekkit.
- [Is there any way to speed up or automate building in the Technic Pack?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/78451/is-there-any-way-to-speed-up-or-automate-building-in-the-technic-pack)
  Not asking about a specific mod, but if there's a way to accomplish something with whatever's in the Technic Pack. Should be tagged Technic Pack, but the Tekkit tag should go.
- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79040/are-there-any-alternatives-to-tekkit-that-offer-similar-features
  Closed, but it's again not asking about a specific mod: it's asking for a recommendation about something that works like the Tekkit pack. Should be tagged Tekkit, if not some wacky meta-tag like "mod recommendation". Probably should just be speedy deleted to avoid the whole issue.
- [How can I recover from a world wipe due to the Technic Pack?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75991/how-can-i-recover-from-a-world-wipe-due-to-the-technic-pack)
  Not asking about a specific mod; it's specifically asking how to recover due to a problem/"feature" with the pack. Should be tagged Technic Pack.
- [How can I disable logs spawning leaves in Technic Pack 6.1.1?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76873/how-can-i-disable-logs-spawning-leaves-in-technic-pack-6-1-1)
  This one does not specify a specific mod, but it's likely it's caused by a specific mod. Since we don't know, we have to take the question at face value. It's asking about Technic Pack functionality, so it should be tagged as such. It probably should be closed as NARQ until the user updates the question with more info; at which time we could tag it with the right mod (if necessary) or re-frame it to no longer apply to Technic Pack.

Comment: Actually 4 and 5 aren't about the pack, number 4 is about the launcher and number 5 is about redpower.

Comment: Actually 5 isn't redpower, but it's a mod in the pack, not the pack itself.

Comment: @RonanForman I would consider the launcher to be part of the pack: it'd be silly to have a [tag:minecraft-technic-pack-launcher] tag. Re: 5; if there's not enough information to determine what part of Technic Pack is causing the problem, we should close it as NARQ until it's updated. Removing the tag now is hasty since that's all we know about the question.